# GLFW3 multiple windows

Tags: glfw, window-management

I'm trying to use GLFW3 to develop VJing application. So basic idea is use two windows:

1st window for fullscreen projection on secondary monitor (basically projector)

2nd window for (hopefully) fullscreen GUI.

It does not have to share context, as GUI window will be just using [libRocket](http://librocket.com/) for controlling content, recieving MIDI & OSC commands, etc.

Problem is that so far, when I switch projection window on second monitor to fullscreen, it runs, but as soon as I move mouse to primary monitor and click somewhere, projection window gets minimized. Also, GUI window gets a poor framerate.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

using namespace std;

void errorCallback(int error, const char *description){
fputs(description, stderr);
}

static void keyCallback(GLFWwindow *window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods){
if (key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_RELEASE)
{
    glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);
}
}


int main(){


glfwSetErrorCallback(errorCallback);
if (!glfwInit())
{
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

int MonitorCount;
GLFWmonitor ** monitors = glfwGetMonitors(&MonitorCount);

//GLFWvidmode* modes = glfwGetVideoModes(monitors, &MonitorCount); 

GLFWwindow *window;
window = glfwCreateWindow(1024, 768,"Projection", monitors[0], NULL);
GLFWwindow *controls;
controls = glfwCreateWindow(1024, 768, "Controls", glfwGetPrimaryMonitor(), NULL);

glfwSetKeyCallback(window, keyCallback);
while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)){


     //// PROJECTION WINDOW
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    float ratio;
    int width, height;
    glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &width, &height);
    ratio = width / (float) height;
    glViewport(0,0, width, height);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

      glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(-ratio, ratio, -1.f, 1.f, 1.f, -1.f);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glRotatef((float) glfwGetTime() * 50.f, 0.f, 0.f, 1.f);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glColor3f(1.f, 0.f, 0.f);
    glVertex3f(-0.6f, -0.4f, 0.f);
    glColor3f(0.f, 1.f, 0.f);
    glVertex3f(0.6f, -0.4f, 0.f);
    glColor3f(0.f, 0.f, 1.f);
    glVertex3f(0.f, 0.6f, 0.f);
    glEnd();

    //// ---- CONTROL WINDOW ---- 
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(controls);
    glfwGetFramebufferSize(controls, &width, &height);
    ratio = width / (float) height;
    glViewport(0,0, width, height);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

          glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(-ratio, ratio, -1.f, 1.f, 1.f, -1.f);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glRotatef((float) glfwGetTime() * 100.f, 0.f, 0.f, 1.f);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glColor3f(0.f, 0.f, 0.f);
    glVertex3f(-0.6f, -0.4f, 0.f);
    glColor3f(0.f, 1.f, 0.f);
    glVertex3f(0.6f, -0.4f, 0.f);
    glColor3f(0.f, 0.f, 1.f);
    glVertex3f(0.f, 0.6f, 0.f);
    glEnd();

    glfwSwapBuffers(controls);
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);


    glfwPollEvents();
}

glfwDestroyWindow(controls);
glfwDestroyWindow(window);
glfwTerminate();
exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

}
```

I'm on Win7 / VS2012 using nVidia 680m

Comment: Did you already resolve why it has low fps when multi window? I'm also planning to make an app that has two monitors at the same time using glfw3.

Comment: I think our assumptions here were wrong. I try to unlock the fps from 60 on every loop by putting this inside the loop `glfwSwapInterval(GL_FALSE);` and I get a high fps but still it's glitching, any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

Set the [GLFW_AUTO_ICONIFY](http://www.glfw.org/docs/3.2/window_guide.html#window_hints_wnd) window hint to false to disable automatic iconification of full screen windows.